# Lazy-load html content from list?

Tags: jekyll, amp-html

I am in the process of converting my website into a single-page AMP website. I want to provide the current html section initially (using a Jekyll `include`), but I also want every other section to load lazily as sections become available.

If I understand correctly, the amp-list partially works like this, but it requires a template, loads all items at once and raw html is serialized.

Would any AMP component be able to do this? Could I insert html with a script instead? Or create my own custom component?

Here is what I have so far:

```html
<main id="main-content">
    <!-- {{ content }} being the current section -->
    {{ content }}
</main>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What do you mean with dynamically? Lazy load or different content that depend on a action. You can add dynamic content via php on server site. What do wan't do?

Comment: Yes I am referring to lazy loading. I want to avoid the user having to wait for the entire website to load before they can view the section of the website they requested.
I will edit my original question to better reflect this.

Comment: I tried my absolute best, but I think AMP is just not ready for my use-cases. I will be looking into phasing it out later today. Meaning that I no longer need this question to be answered. If anyone does submit an answer, I will still review it!